# Defining event callbacks in a python class

Tags: python

I have a class that I want to serve as a wrapper, and contain other classes.

I asimple stub would be this:

```
class DiscordBot():

    DiscordClient = discord.Client() 
    Token = None 


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if "token" in kwargs:
            self.SetToken(kwargs["token"])


    def SetToken(self, tkn):
        self.Token = str(tkn).strip()


    @DiscordClient.event
    async def on_message(self,message):
         pass
```

However, I can't do this.. because when that on_message event gets fired, you will get a stack trace of

```
"TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'"
```

Which I guess make sense since a different type will be passed in in the required slot.
Is there a way to make this function a member of the 'DiscordBot' class, that way to be able to access all the same variables as well?

I am sure there is another way to define this.. just not sure how!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `on_message` is a static method, and you should just remove `self` ? See https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=event#discord.Client.event